# Android Developer Console - Uninstall apps

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-console

Is there anyway to delete `play store applications` which installed on user phones ?

I mean does `Android Developer Console` Have kind of settings witch allow Developers to uninstall apps on user phones ?

Answer (score 4):

You can unpublish an app from the Play Store but you can't force the uninstall of your app from users devices.